# ext4:disagress about version of symbol dquot_alloc,ext4:unknown symbol dquot_alloc(err -22)

Tags: linux, mount, kernel-modules

I am customizing a Linux system and I am not sure why. I have entered the following interface:

[image]

Comment: did you rebuild the kernel without reinstalling their matching modules, *including* in the initramfs/initrd boot?

Comment: @A.B Yes, I recompiled the kernel, but I'm not sure which option was changed? And in the screenshot above, the keyboard cannot be used, I don't know why?During the Grub boot process in the previous stage, the keyboard was still usable.